# Combine passing a complete context (or an action's outputs) to another action and add additional variables

Tags: json, yaml, github-actions

[In this related answer I'm taking all of the outputs of one action and I pass them to the environment of the next action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76317160/split-string-line-by-line-and-variablize-i-e-assign-it-to-github-output-workfl/76317691#76317691).

I'd like to know how to add additional variables or to add more than one context, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

This works:

```yaml
    - run: |
         echo "port=1234" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
         # repeat with another couple of arbitrary environment variables
      id: split
      shell: pwsh
    - run: |
          echo "$($env:port)"    
      shell: pwsh
      env: ${{ steps.split.outputs }}
```

Instead of `steps.split.outputs` I can also pass `vars` or `secrets` or `github` and as a result all if the elements in those contexts are available as environment variables.

But I can't find a syntax that allows me to past 2 different contexts or a context and 2 additional environment variables.

What I'd like to do is to add one or more extra variable to the set of values.

Passing a single context works:

```yaml
    # CORRECT SYNTAX
    - run: |
          echo "$($env:port)"    
      shell: pwsh
      env: 
        ${{ github }}
```

But passing a context and an explicit variable or more than one context fails.

```yaml
    # INCORRECT SYNTAX
    - run: |
          echo "$($env:port)"    
      shell: pwsh
      env: 
        ${{ steps.split.outputs }}
        anothername: withvalue
```

Or add more than one context:

```yaml
    # INCORRECT SYNTAX
    - run: |
          echo "$($env:port)"    
      shell: pwsh
      env: 
        ${{ steps.split.outputs }}
        ${{ vars }}
        anothername: withvalue
```

I can't figure out the correct syntax to "combine" these objects into one so I can send them as a set of variables.

In essence the object being passed is a JSON object, there must be a trick I'm missing. Worst case I'll need to add a step before that builds the desired set of variables.

I know how create a new set of output variables in an extra `run:` step, but it seems there is no way to create a new object/map using just yaml constructs.

Comment: That would be a YAML syntax error as [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) is not a map anymore. Injecting them in a separate step should be the way to go. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691648/how-to-inject-all-github-environment-specific-variables-from-vars-to-env-context

Comment: Microsoft Github Action Expressions aren't template expressions, but within string 
 members of the YALM document. You can encode as JSON Text within an expression thought, and JSON allows you to transport a set of values. Basically what @Azeem already commented, perhaps you should give some more feedback what you're **specifically** looking for. What is your concrete use-case? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a step in one job that sets a couple of output variables. I'm passing all of these variables to a new script step in another stage and its much easier to pass `steps.id.outputs` instead of explicitly mapping each value. But when I do that I'm robbed of the ability to set additional environment variables. I could pass the data as a single object with the `tojson` function, but that would require me to decode.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I've never done it in powershell, but in bash decoding the json back into the environment was not a problem. The transformation can be done w/ `jq` and the result sourced. I can imagine this is similar possible w/ powershell.

Comment: I know that would work, it's just ugly and I was hoping I lacked some yaml knowledge and that there would be a way to combine objects or to add additional keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While passing a single object to the `env` of a step will work, you can't pass multiple objects or a combination of objects and keys.

Instead you can use the `tojson` function to turn each whole object into a json string and pass them with their own key:

```
env:
  values: ${{ toJson(steps.outputs.values) }}
  vars: ${{ toJson(vars) }}
```

The step in question will need to decode these values and turn them into environment variables or into a new set of output variables:

```
$values = $env:values | convertfrom-json -ashashtable
$vars = $env:vars | convertfrom-json -ashashtable

foreach ($key in $values.keys) {
  write-output "$key=$($values."$key")" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
}

foreach ($key in $vars.keys) {
  write-output "$key=$($vars."$key")" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
}
```

You can then reference the output from this step as input to another step that needs these values.